# Better way of defining directory import prefixes?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set prefixes for different directories to use universally throughout my whole site. I do testing on my localhost and upload to my live server when ready. Both servers have the same directory structure. I'm trying to cut time so I can copy/paste certain blocks of code throughout my whole site and keep it all universal (i.e: on ~/index.php the directory prefix would be `./css/*` but in ~/scripts/Shell it would be `../../`. So if I copy/paste all of my imports, I have to go through and change the prefixes in each page).

Right now I came up with this, but I feel like there's gotta be a better way:

```php
$root = ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$realdir = getcwd();
if ($realdir == $root) {
    $prefix = ("./");
} elseif ($realdir == "$root/testing") {
    $prefix = ("../");
} elseif ($realdir == "$root/gallery") {
    $prefix = ("../");
} elseif ($realdir == "$root/comment") {
    $prefix = ("../");
} elseif ($realdir == "$root/commment/uploading") {
    $prefix = ("../../");
} elseif ($realdir == "$root/scripts") {
    $prefix = ("../");
} elseif ($realdir == "$root/scripts/Encoder") {
    $prefix = ("../../");
} elseif ($realdir == ("$root/scripts/Shell")) {
    $prefix = ("../../");
} elseif ($realdir == ("$root/scripts/2FA")) {
    $prefix = ("../../");
}
```

And then this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $prefix.'css/main.css'?>">
```

Prior to this, I was doing this, which is pretty universal when it works, but I don't feel like it's a good way of doing it.

```php
$server = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/";
```

With this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $server.'css/neon.css'?>">
```

I just feel like there's a better way of doing this without having so much clutter.

Comment: It looks fine to me. One alternative might to define an array or object relating paths to prefixes and reference the path values that way. For example, `echo $prefixes[$realdir] . 'css/main.css';` Or would simply defining a common absolute root URL work, like `$rootURL . 'css/main.css'`?

Comment: @showdev, with the latter, are you meaning similar to what I had with defining $server and then `$server.'css/neon.css'` ? That was working perfect across both localhost and my live server until I used Ngrok as a tunnel on localhost. I edited my OP to hopefully clarify what my goal is. Also, I should mention I'm pretty new to PHP.

Maybe counting how many directories the file is away from the root and setting the prefix from there ? I'm not sure if that's possible with PHP.

Comment: Yes, something like that. However, it seems that the `$server` definition might need to be conditional depending on whether you are working locally or live (different root URLs). Also, I'm not sure how tunneling will impact things in this context. You might also find this interesting: [Premature Optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: @showdev, this: `$server = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/";` worked perfect on localhost and my live server until I used Ngrok. Then it was trying to read Ngrok's URL to find the directories.

Comment: I don't have experience with Ngrok. I wonder if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST']` is relevant, as shown in examples [here](https://startingcraft.com/articles/how-to-use-ngrok-with-craftcms).

Comment: I'll have to play around with that. I've just discovered that even setting it up the way I have it with the directory prefixes doesn't work on Ngrok either. Pretty strange. I'm gonna look over the examples in that link and see if I can get it working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't you simply mention relative path?

Comment: @showdev, I think I found my solution to cut down on clutter with all those `if/elseif` statements: `$depth = count(explode('/', (parse_url($full_url, PHP_URL_PATH)))) - 2;`. Now I should be able to do something like: `if $depth = 1; prefix = '../';elseif $depth ==2:prefix="../../"`, etc.

Comment: Just use root-relative links for everything: `href="/css/main.css"`. Done. Works from any and all pages you're on, as long as the CSS file is at `http://<hostname>/css/main.css`.

Comment: @deceze, I only was looking for an alternative because that wasn't seeming to work with Ngrok and I wanted something completely universal(localhost, live and Ngrok). But I came to find out that it wasn't any of this that was causing Ngrok to fail. Not sure what it is yet, but this project was a big waste of time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `$realdir` is always inside the `$root`.
The idea is to cut off the root prefix and get as much `..` as the `$realdir` depth is. Using regexp for example:

```
<?php
$root = '/path/to/the/server/root';
$realdir = '/path/to/the/server/root/commment/uploading';

$prefix = ltrim(
    preg_replace(
        "#[^/]+#",
        '..',
        mb_substr( $realdir, mb_strlen($root) )
    ),
    '/'
);

print $prefix;
```

If you need to link a resource from the root, you might refer it just like for example `href="/path/from/root/file.css"`. Browser will add proto, host, port.